# Shell variables in sed script

Tags: sed

The sed command works as expected at the command prompt, but does not work in a shell script.

```
new_db_name=`echo "$new_db_name" | sed 's/$replace_string/$replace_with/'`
```

Why is that, and how can I fix it?

Comment: With single quotes, the variables do not get replaced with their values.

Comment: This won't work in an interactive session either.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Use double quotes for the `sed` expression.

```
new_db_name=$(echo "$new_db_name" | sed "s/$replace_string/$replace_with/")
```

Answer (score 6):

If you use bash, this should work:

```
new_db_name=${new_db_name/$replace_string/$replace_with}
```

Comment: `new_db_name=${new_db_name//$replace_string/$replace_with}` if you want to replace all (notice the double `//`)

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me in using env arguments.

```
export a=foo
export b=bar

echo a/b | sed 's/a/'$b'/'

bar/b
```

Answer (score 1):

Guys: I used the following to pass bash variables to a function in a bash script using sed. I.e., I passed bash variables to a sed command.

```
#!/bin/bash                            
function solveOffendingKey(){

    echo "We will delete the offending key in file: $2, in line: $1"
    sleep 5
    eval "sed -i '$1d' $2"
}


line='4'
file=~/ivan/known_hosts
solveOffendingKey $number $file
```

Kind regards!

Answer (score 0):

depending on how your variables are initialized, you are better off using brackets:

```
new_db_name=`echo "$new_db_name" | sed "s/${replace_string}`/${replace_with}/"
```

Maybe I'm missing something but `new_db_name=echo "$new_db_name"` doesn't make sense here. $new_db_name is empty so you're echoing a null result, and then the output of the sed command. To capture stdout as a variable, backticks aren't recommended anymore. Capture output surrounded by `$()`.

```
new_db_name=$(sed "s/${replace_string}/${replace_with}/")
```

Take the following example:

```
replace_string="replace_me"
replace_with=$(cat replace_file.txt | grep "replacement_line:" | awk FS" '{print $1}')
```

Where replace_file.txt could look something like:

```
old_string: something_old
I like cats
replacement_line: "shiny_new_db"
```

Just having the variable in the sed expresion `$replace_with` won't work. bash doesn't have enough context to escape the variable expression. `${replace_with}` tells bash to explicitly use the contents of the command issued by the variable.