# Sed -i assistance (bash)

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I'm new to Sed and as you might imagine you can get lost early ...

I have the following variable in a PHP page I'm trying to change using a bash script:

```
$username='';
```

I want to give it an expanded variable value stored in $myUsername so that the final entry looks like:

```
$username='someName';
```

I believe I'm close with the following, but can't seem to cross that finish line ...

```
sed -i 's/"$username = ''".*$/\$username = /"${myUsername}/"' /var/www/settings.php
```

Thanks for the education / help

Comment: Why do you have all the double quotes inside the regex? `sed` will try to match those and fail.

Comment: possible duplicate of [shell variables in sed script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7006910/shell-variables-in-sed-script)

Comment: Note that this is fine for usernames, but won't work if you have data containing the `/` character; more involved techniques are necessary to work with arbitrary data.

Comment: (also, `sed -i` is not a POSIX-standard option, so don't be surprised if scripts in which you use it don't work on other operating systems).

Comment: Thank you all for the additional comments, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there, use for example this improved version:

```
sed -i "s/\$username = ''/\$username = '$myUsername'/" file
```

Note that to use a variable you need to use double quotes. Otherwise, the variable won't be expanded. Also, that's why escaping `$username` with `\$username` is needed, to avoid it being interpreted as the bash variable `$username`.

#### Test

```
$ cat a
hello
$username = '';
bye

$ myUsername="bu"
$ sed "s/\$username = ''/\$username = '$myUsername'/" a
hello
$username = 'bu';
bye

$ myUsername="hello"
$ sed "s/\$username = ''/\$username = '$myUsername'/" a
hello
$username = 'hello';
bye
```

#### Improvement

You can also improve the approach by catching a block. It works with `\( block \)` syntax, printing it back with `\1`:

```
$ sed "s/\(\$username = \)''/\1'$myUsername'/" a
hello
$username = 'hello';
bye
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I knew about the " for expansion and thought I was indeed close.  Much appreciated.