# How to parse variable to sed command in shell?

Tags: shell, sed, freebsd

I have some variables:

```
$begin=10
$end=20
```

how to pass them to `sed` command.

```
sed -n '$begin,$endp' filename | grep word
sed -n '10,20p' filename | grep word
```

Comment: you can put the grepping logic in sed:  try `sed -n "$begin,$end{/word/p}" file`

Comment: possible duplicate of [shell variables in sed script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7006910/shell-variables-in-sed-script)

Answer (score 3):

The reason this doesn't work is that single quotes in shell code prevent variable expansion. The good way is to use awk:

```
awk -v begin="$begin" -v end="$end" 'NR == begin, NR == end' filename
```

It is *possible* with sed if you use double quotes (in which shell variables are expanded):

```
sed -n "$begin,$end p" filename
```

However, this is subject to code injection vulnerabilities because sed cannot distinguish between code and data this way (unlike the awk code above). If a user manages to set, say, `end="20 e rm -Rf /;"`, unpleasant things can happen.