# Extract range of lines using sed

Tags: bash, sed

I have defined two variables as follows:

```
var1=$(unzip -c ./*.zip | grep -n "Channel8"| cut -f1 -d":")
var2=$(unzip -c ./*.zip | grep -n "Channel10"| cut -f1 -d":")
```

I have a very big file and I would like to extract the range of lines between `$var1` and `$var2` using sed. I am trying the following

```
sed -n '/"$var1","$var"2p' $(unzip -c ./*.zip)
```

But with no success. Could you give an explanation why and how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Within single quotes, nothing is expanded and you keep literal `"$var1"` in your command instead of what they expand to.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [shell variables in sed script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7006910/shell-variables-in-sed-script)

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3306007/replace-a-string-in-shell-script-using-a-variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
unzip -c ./*.zip | sed -n "$var1,$var2 p"
```

Fixes are:

- Not using single quotes around shell variable
- Removal of leading `/` from sed command
- Use of pipeline instead of command substitution

Comment: Why the character p is with white space?

Comment: If there is no space before `p` then shell will attempt to expand `var2p` without any command and will generate syntax error

Answer (score 3):

Variables aren't expanded inside single quotes. Also, you need to pipe the output of `unzip` to `sed`, not use it as command-line arguments.

```
unzip -c ./*.zip | sed -n "${var1},${var2}p"
```

But it seems like you're doing this the hard way, reading the zip file 3 times. Just use the pattern you want to match as the range:

```
unzip -c ./*.zip | sed -n '/^extracting:.*Channel8/,/^extracting:.*Channel10/p'
```

Comment: Why are you using :/,/ in between sed?

Comment: @JPV A sed address can be a line number or a pattern. If it's a pattern, it goes between two slashes.

Comment: This being said, I don't think the colons should be here, they come from `grep -n` in the original question.

Comment: I did it in the hard way because maybe I need to select 2 lined up from var1 and 4 lines up from var2. So I want to modify my variables

Comment: @BenjaminW. No, they come from `unzip -c`. It displays `filename:`

Comment: My `unzip -c` doesn't display any filenames followed by a colon.

Comment: You're right, I misread the output. I saw `Archive:`, I thought that was a filename.

Answer (score 1):

Use double quotes to expand the vars:

```
sed -n "${var1},${var2}p" $(unzip -c ./*.zip)
```